# Change the language of a LaTeX document

Tags: languages, babel

Is there any way to change which language LaTeX works in? I'm writing a report in danish, but when I use `\maketitle` and other commands which generates some content. This content appears in english. Is there any way to change this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5764) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 16):

Try `\usepackage[danish]{babel}`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5764) Your answer was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or edit your answer.